# Generic type check - keep type and not dynamic

Tags: dart, generics

I have these classes

```dart
class CustomPopupAction<T> extends CustomAction {
  final Icon icon;
  final List<CustomPopupActionItem<T>> actions;
  final void Function(T) onActionSelected;

  CustomPopupAction({
    required this.icon,
    required this.actions,
    required this.onActionSelected,
  });
}

class CustomPopupActionItem<T> {
  final T value;
  final Widget Function(T) itemBuilder;

  CustomPopupActionItem({
    required this.value,
    required this.itemBuilder,
  });
}
```

and I am trying to create overflow menu which will work like this:

- if the button is visible, I will create `PopupMenuButton`
- if the button is overflown, I will create `ListTile` which will open dialog
- it can hold multiple different types like `CustomAction`, `CustomPopupAction<Locale>`, `CustomPopupAction<String>`...

I am building that row like this

```dart
if (a is CustomPopupAction) {
  return PopupMenuButton(
    icon: a.icon,
    onSelected: (i) => a.onActionSelected(i),
    itemBuilder: (context) {
      return a.actions.map((i) => PopupMenuItem(
        value: i.value,
        child: i.itemBuilder(i.value),
      )).toList();
    },
  );
} else {
  return IconButton(...);
}
```

and finally my main code:

```dart
...
return OverflowMenu(
  actions: [
    CustomPopupAction<Locale>(
      icon: Icon(Icons.translate),
      actions: [
        CustomPopupActionItem<Locale>(
          value: Locale('en'),
          itemBuilder: (l) => ListTile(title: Text(l.toString()),
        ),
      ],
    onActionSelected: (l) => print(l),
  ],
);
```

But this doesn't work for me, I am getting an exception `Expected a value of type '(dynamic) => Widget', but got one of type '(Locale) => ListTile'.`

I know it's because `if (a is CustomPopupAction)` is actually getting `CustomPopupAction<dynamic>`.

1. can I somehow convince Dart that `a` nas not dynamic type and that it should work with it's real type?
2. if not, why am I getting that exception? `Locale` can be assigned to `dynamic` variable and `ListTile` is clearly a `Widget`.
3. can I do this without going through dynamics at all?

Comment: When you do `a is CustomPopupAction`, you're really doing `a is CustomPopupAction<dynamic>`.  If the condition is true, `a` therefore will be promoted to `CustomPopupAction<dynamic>`.  If you want to avoid `dynamic`, you will need to supply an explicit type parameter.  If you don't know that type *statically*, then that inherently means that you will need to perform additional *runtime* type checks.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. What kind of runtime type checks you mean? Like check against the exact type e.g. `CustomPopupAction<Locale>`? That would be a lot of checks. Also don't you know why am I getting that exception when those types (Locale -> dynamic, ListTile -> Widget) should be compatible?